# Bitwise replacing bits in two numbers

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, solidity

I'm interested how I can swap interval of bits from number X to number Y using bitwise operations.

So for example I have number:

X = 00000000
Y = 00111111

positionStart, positionEnd

And I want to replace [positionStart, positionEnd] bits in X with bits from Y at the same position.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, I think that it's possible with Bitwise OR

x = x | (y & (1 << positionStart));

Comment: Replacing bits in X with bits in Y is not the same as swapping - should the bits from X also go back to Y?

Comment: @harold no, sorry for miscommunication, I need only to replace X bits with Y.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a mask `m` that indicates the bits that you want to move or swap, you could move them like this:

```
x = x ^ ((x ^ y) & m)
```

Or swap them like this:

```
t = (x ^ y) & m
x ^= t
y ^= t
```

This could be explained as taking the bitwise difference between `x` and `y`, only in places where `m` is set. Then XORing `x` with that flips the bits in `x` where `x` and `y` are different (and `m` is set) so it changes those bits of `x` into bits of `y`. The same thing applies to `y`.

---

A mask might be created like

```
m = (2 << end) - (1 << start)
```

Comment: Not sure that I have a mask, I have the position. I can probably create the mask based on position, but not sure how.

Comment: @StupidFox it depends a bit on what the start and end positions mean (eg is the end inclusive of exclusive, do they count from lsb up or from msb down, can they span the entire integer, etc), jdehesa gives a decent way but there are other possibilities

Comment: bits count from the right side from zero, start and end positions inclusively. I'm writing it on solidity, but the general concept on c++ looks the same. @harold

Comment: How does `x ^= t` work? Wouldn't 0 bits out of the mask in `x` be swapped?

Comment: @jdehesa what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

First make a mask (this assumes Python-like indexing from least to most significant, zero-based and not including the upper index):

```
M = (1 << positionEnd) - 1) & ~((1 << positionStart) - 1)
```

If you want to replace the bits in `X` with those in `Y`:

```
X = (X & ~M) | (Y & M)
```

If you want to swap, you can use a third variable or can do something like a masked [XOR trick](https://betterexplained.com/articles/swap-two-variables-using-xor/):

```
X = (X & ~M) | ((X ^ Y) & M)
Y = (Y & ~M) | ((X ^ Y) & M)
X = (X & ~M) | ((X ^ Y) & M)
```