# How would I replace the 3 above bits in brackets with the 3 bits below in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

How would I replace the above bits in brackets with the bits below in brackets?

```
000[1 11]11
000[0 11]00
```

Comment: I have added the [tag:c] tag to your question.  It's important to add appropriate tags to a question so the users best able to help you will see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitwise replacing bits in two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948962/bitwise-replacing-bits-in-two-numbers)

Comment: 0x1F ^ 0x03.  That would via xor

Comment: This has an entry in [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ConditionalSetOrClearBitsWithoutBranching).

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 0b00011111
y = 0b00001100
z = 0b00001111
```

First we take the bits we want to keep from x.

```
zOuter = (x & 0b11100011)
```

Then we take only the bits we want from y.

```
zMiddle = (y & 0b00011100)
```

Then we put them all together.

```
z = zOuter | zMidle = (x & 0b11100011) | (y & 0b00011100)
```

Comment: `z = 00001111` This is not what `x & (00011100 | y)` evaluates to.

Comment: Wouldn't this possibly remove bits of ```x``` outside of bracket? And bits in bracket of ```x``` will not change.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I messed this up. Taking a second look.

Comment: @MarkSouls should be the correct answer now.

Comment: @AlexRiveron `z = (x & 11100011) | (x & 00011100 | y)` This is still wrong. Also, you provide no explanation of what the formula does, or why (you think) it would solve OP's problem.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry again, I think I fixed it now. Sorry for polluting this answer. Clearly not helpful and probably confusing to the OP.

Comment: @AlexRiveron Closer, but still wrong. "*we combine only the middle parts from x and y*" But the question is not about combining them, it's about taking the middle part from `y` alone. The `x` should not even appear in the second parenthesis.

Comment: @dxiv ah... that's right... I should not have tried answering this... Let's give it another shot. It's becoming a bit of a challenge.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for the feedback. I think it's correct now.

Comment: @AlexRiveron You forgot to fix the `zMiddle = ` line, but other than that, yes, that's correct.

Comment: Fixed the line and cleaned up the solution a bit.

Answer (score 1):

#### Swap bits with a mask:

You can swap bits with a mask the following way:

```c
void swap_bits_mask(int *a, int *b, int mask)
{
    *a ^= *b & mask;
    *b ^= *a & mask; // b now has the masked bits from a
    *a ^= *b & mask; // now it is the turn for a to get the masked bits from b
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 0b00011111;
    int b = 0b10001100;
    int m = 0b00011100;

    printf("%d %d\n", a,b);
    swap_bits_mask(&a, &b, m);
    printf("%d %d\n", a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Its basically the swap of two integers, modified with a mask.

NB: You will notice that I added 1 bit to b, it was to make sure my function works as intended.